# Mismatched Encoding

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

I work with `Android Studio 1.2.2` and `Windows 8.1 Pro` in `Germany`.
When I created a new project, it opens with an error for project encoding.

I have  read http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding, which written about this error (This is exactly the same error.)

The article says:
"When you encounter the above problem (which points to the this page), either change your `IDE` settings or `build.gradle` to `UTF-8` such that the two matches, or (if necessary) change your encoding to whatever `custom encoding` you have specified such that the two are in agreement. "

That's why I changed all settings to `UTF-8` and the `Message Grandle Sync` is off.

But when trying to put `German text` in `Android-Studio`, it shows just "?" characters when running the app.

That's why I put the second note:

"If you do change the encoding in the `IDE`, make sure you also update the `Gradle` files to reflect these encodings:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, I continue to get the ? instead of umlauts Ää Öö Üü and ß.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android Studio` default file encoding is `windows-1252`, thats the cause for what you are seeing this characters:

[image]

You can convert your file to `UTF-8` and will display with no problem your characters "umlauts Ää Öö Üü and ß", see the image attached.

[image]

This is an example showing your text in a `Toast`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Elenanis, Your Note is good. However, he does not solve my problem.
The representation of the umlauts in the code (for example as in comments) is correct.
But my problem is the appearance of the umlauts when the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

Elenasys, thank you for your help. This has solve my problem. 
I made the mistake to write my code, while the encoding was set to Windows 1252. Switching to UTF-8 brought wrong characters and then of course, this wrong characters came at the start of the app. Now I have corrected these characters, (ie I have these characters reentered after setting the correct coding), and now everything works!